# Como transformar uma string em um array

Tags: java, array

Boa galera, seguinte como posso transformar uma string em um array?
Por exemplo: String teste = "345,421,888,211";

Explicando o contexto, esse valores são Id's que concatenei em uma string oriundos de uma grid.
Após transforma-los em array, entra a outra duvida, como faço pra percorrer o array?

Ps: Sou iniciante em java, seria de muita ajuda essa informações.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que isso te ajuda..

```
String teste = "345,421,888,211";

    //Vou dividir a string quando encontrar o caractere ","
    String[] teste2 = teste.split(",");

    //Aqui vou percorrer o array criado e printar o código
    for(int i=0; i<teste2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Codigo:" + teste2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: vlw, ajudou demais !

Comment: Marque como correta, caso seja a resposta para a sua pergunta. :)